# How to echo php and html of dropdown list?

Tags: php, html

I have problem with my codes and I'm still new to php. Please help me :)

```
echo "<td><select>
    <option value='1'<?php if($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '1') { ?> selected='selected'<?php } ?>>1</option>;

    <option value='2'<?php if($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '2') { ?> selected='selected'<?php } ?>>2</option>;

    <option value='3'<?php if($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '3') { ?> selected='selected'<?php } ?>>3</option>;

</select></td>";
```

I am expecting the dropdown list that I have selected before edit will be selected in the edit page. But it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

When echoing, you are already in a php context, so there is no need to use `<?php ?>` tags again. You can just concatenate the variables in your string.

```
echo "<td><select>

    <option value='1'" . ($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '1' ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . ">1</option>;

    <option value='2'" . ($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '2' ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . ">2</option>;

    <option value='3'" . ($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '3' ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . ">3</option>;

</select></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td><select>
    <option value='1'<?php if($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '1') { echo ' selected'; } ?>>1</option>
    <option value='2'<?php if($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '2') { echo ' selected'; } ?>>2</option>
    <option value='3'<?php if($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '3') { echo ' selected'; } ?>>3</option>
</select></td>
```

You only need `;` when working inside the `<?php ?>` tags so strip those out. Also save the opening and closing by just echoing out the selected value. Also the correct syntax is `selected` and not `selected='selected'`

Answer (score 0):

you can not echo a string and put php code into the string

correct code:

```
<td>
<select>
    <option value='1'<?php if($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '1') { ?> selected='selected'<?php } ?>>1</option>
    <option value='2'<?php if($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '2') { ?> selected='selected'<?php } ?>>2</option>
    <option value='3'<?php if($row['Staf_Kamp'] == '3') { ?> selected='selected'<?php } ?>>3</option>
</select>
</td>
```